# How I put water mark in iReport for my pdf Documents...?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want one image on my pdf documents which is Opaque that is my text as well seen to my user.

Comment: PDF only, or all versions?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this placing the background watermark image in the **Background** band in the iReport/JasperSoft Studio

Thanks